# How to get button click function to work before submitting the form with a different button?

Tags: javascript

I have 3 buttons, one of which submits (submit) the form and another that populates input windows with random data (rand):

```
  <div type="input">
    <input type="submit" id="submit";">
    <input type="button" id="rand" value="Random";">
    <input type="reset" id="log" value="Log" onclick="window.location.href='log.txt';">
  </div>
```

I am not able to get the random button to populate input windows with random data until after I have submitted the form. How do I debug so that I do not need to submit the form before I can populate the input screens?

```
<body>



  <h1>Payment Form</h1>
    <form id="myForm" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post";>
      <div type="input">
        <div>
          <label>First Name </label>
          <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Last Name </label>
          <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname">
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Student ID </label>
          <input type="text" name="studentid" id="studentid">
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Tuition </label>
          <input type="text" name="tuition" id="tuition"> <br>
        </div>
      <div>
        <label>Payment Method </label>
        <select name="selection" id="selection">
            <option value="credit">Credit</option>
            <option value="debit">Debit</option>
            <option value="bitcoin">Bitcoin</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div type="input">
        <input type="submit" id="submit";">
        <input type="button" id="rand" value="Random";">
        <input type="reset" id="log" value="Log" onclick="window.location.href='log.txt';">
      </div>
    </form>
  <br> 
     <div id="output">
       <ul></ul>
     </div>


<?php

  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
  {

    if (isset($_POST[firstname]) && isset($_POST[lastname]) && isset($_POST[studentid]) && isset($_POST[tuition]) && isset($_POST[selection]))
    {
        $success = 0;
        $frstnm = $_POST[firstname];
        $lstnm = $_POST[lastname];
        $stdntd = $_POST[studentid];
        $ttn = $_POST[tuition];
        $slctn = $_POST[selection];
        $slctn = ucwords($slctn);
        $dataarray = [$frstnm,$lstnm,$stdntd,$ttn,$slctn];

        if (strlen($frstnm) < 2)
        {
          $myerror = "<li> First name must be 2 or more characters in length";
        }
        if ((strlen($lstnm) < 3) || (strlen($lstnm) > 12))
        {
          $myerror .= "<li> Last name must be between 3 and 12 characters in length";
        }
        if (strlen($stdntd) != 9)
        {
          $myerror .= "<li> Student id must be exactly 9 characters in length";
        }
        if (($ttn < 2000) || ($ttn > 10000))
        {
          $myerror .= "<li> Tuition must be between 2000 and 10000";
        }
        if(strlen($myerror)==0)
        {
          $myerror = "Payment Successful!";
          $success = 1;
        }
        if($success == 1){
          $fp = fopen('log.txt', 'a');
          fputcsv($fp, $dataarray);
          fclose($fp);
        }
    }
  }
?>
<div id="output2"></div>

<script>

   if(<?php echo $success ?>== 1){
    document.getElementById("output").className = "success";
   }
   else{
    document.getElementById("output").className = "error";
   }

   <?php 
   echo "document.getElementById('output').innerHTML ='".$myerror."'";
   ?>


  $("#rand").click(
      function()
      {
        $.get("rangen.php",
        {},
        function(data)
        {
        $("#firstname").val(data.firstname);
        $("#lastname").val(data.lastname); 
        $("#studentid").val(data.studentid);
        $("#tuition").val(data.tuition);
        $("#selection").val(data.method.toLowerCase());
        },'json');
      }
  );


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load the page for the first time, i.e, before submitting the form, the following variables are not defined:

1. `$success`
2. `$myerror`

Thus, while rendering the page, `if(<?php echo $success ?>== 1)` results in something like :`<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: success in <b><<filename>></b> on line <b>95</b><br />`. Similar error occurs for `$myerror`.

These errors prevent the rest of the code in the script tag from being executed. Hence, the  `$("#rand").click()` function never works.

These errors can be fixed by checking for their existence using the `isset()` function before echoing out their values.

1. `if(<?php echo $success ?>== 1)` should be changed to : `if(isset($success)){echo $success;}else{echo 0;}`
2. `echo "document.getElementById('output').innerHTML ='".$myerror."'";` shoulb be changed to `if(isset($myerror)){
   echo "document.getElementById('output').innerHTML ='".$myerror."'";
   }`

Hope this helps!

Comment: before submitting the form, the following variables are not defined:

$success